# Почему вопросы и ответы даются на английском языке?

Tags: discussion

> Если этот ресурс предназначен для всех любителей русского языка, тогда
>   почему вопросы и ответы на вопросы, в большинстве своем, приводятся на
>   Английском языке. Не будет ли полезнее для всех отвечать и спрашивать
>   на русском языке? Я думаю, для изучающих русский язык это будет
>   хорошим стимулом подумать прежде чем спрашивать.

It seems like I know the answer, the StackOverflow does not allow to enter the question body on Russian.

Comment: дубликат http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/382

Comment: I realize this question is old now, but I'm just leaving a reminder for people who come across it in the future: please keep all posts on meta in English, so the Community Managers at SE (like me) can keep up to date on what's going on. It's fine to write in Russian, as long as the English is there too, the way the [community FAQ](http://meta.russian.stackexchange.com/questions/251/russian-se-community-faq) does it.

Answer (score 6):

Ну например, не всегда вопрошающий может сформулировать по-русски, чего хочет, и не для каждого пишущего ответить будет по-русски удобнее.

Как вариант тоже.

Answer (score 2):

Стек про русский язык - один из множества стеков про изучение языка. Подобная дискуссия происходила на этих стеках тоже. В итоге по факту сообщества пришли более-менее к одному, а именно:

1. Этот ресурс для всех, кто интересуется изучением языка, далеко не все люди владеют языком в такой степени, чтобы задать вопрос на этом языке.
2. Как ни странно, люди, которые могут дать на какой-то вопрос хороший ответ не во всех случаях могут его дать на этом языке.
3. Иногда человек прекрасно владеет (в данном случае) русским, но хочет ответить по-английски, чтобы аудитория, способная извлечь пользу из ответа, была заведомо шире.

Так что все стеки про языки де-факто двуязычны. Чаще всего, но далеко не всегда, ответы даются на том же языке, на котором задавался вопрос.  Хорошим тоном является сопроводить свой ответ коротким переводом, если очевидно, что автор хуже владеет языком, на котором дан ответ.